# javascript passing function as parameter

Tags: javascript

If I have this:

```
$(SomeID).on({
    click: function () { SomeFunction1(); },
    mouseenter: function () { SomeFunction2(); },
    mouseleave:function () { SomeFunction3(); }
}, '.SomeClass');
```

I can rewrite it as

```
$(SomeID).on({
    click: SomeFunction1,
    mouseenter: SomeFunction2,
    mouseleave: SomeFunction3
}, '.SomeClass');
```

But what if I need to pass some parameter like this:

```
$(SomeID).on({
    click: function () { SomeFunction1($(this)); },
    mouseenter: function () { SomeFunction2($(this).index()); },
    mouseleave: function () { SomeFunction3($(this).index()); }
}, '.SomeClass');
```

Is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: You need not to pass `this` , it will be available to those those functions.

Comment: I think his question is how to shorten the code with parameters in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jashwant says, the same `this` would be used in the function anyway, so it's the one value you don't need to worry about (in your example).

Note that you could do as you describe if you needed to, it's easy for static values, and is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). A javascript example would be: http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/

Comment: (nitpick: it isn't exactly currying, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application )

Answer (score 1):

You should modify implementation of `SomeFunction`s to get them work without parameter.

For example, if you have:

```
function SomeFunction2(arg) {
  //do something assuming arg to be $(this).index()
}
```

You can write it like that:

```
function SomeFunction2() {
  var arg = $(this).index();
  //do exactly the same
}
```

After doing that for all three callbacks, you can use your second code sample to bind them.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `this` inside a javascript function does not depend on the lexical scope the function was defined in – for example, the following alerts "Hello, World!", event if `this.name` is not defined when `greet` is created

```
var x = { name: 'World' };
var greet = function() { alert('Hello, ' + this.name); };
x.greet = greet;
x.greet();
```

the following too alerts "Hello, World!":

```
var x = { name: 'World' };
var y = { name: 'Dude', greet: function() { alert('Hello, ' + this.name); } };
x.greet = y.greet;
x.greet();
```

Behind the scenes, what goes on is similar to:

```
var greet = function() { alert('Hello, ' + this.name); };
greet.call({ name: 'World' });
```

So you can safely mix your #2 and #3 snippets.

**BTW:**

most jQuery event handlers get called with a reference to the jQuery event object as the first parameter, so if you find how `this` works tricky (or if you fear you'll have to explain to each one of you colleagues), you can also use `event.delegateTarget` instead of `this`.

See for example:

```
$(document).click(function(evt){ alert (evt.delegateTarget === this); });
```